# Count columns in a table and count columns in joint table

Tags: sql, ssms-2014

I'm using SSMS 2014 and I'd like to do two things:

i) Count the number of columns in a table called 'aggregatedsaleshistory.'

I understand that I'd have to write something similar to this. Can you please modify the code where it's wrong?

```
select count (*) from aggregatedsaleshistory where table_name ='aggregatedsaleshistory'
```

ii) count the number of columns if that table is joined to another table.

e.g with the code below, I'm getting the Category and Subcategory data from the Enterprise Structure view and a sum of the Units and Cash Sales for them from the Aggregated Sales History table.

```
select
    es.CategoryName,
    es.SubCategoryName,   
    format(sum(ash.Sales), '#,###') as Units,
    format(sum(ash.price * ash.Sales), '#,###') as CashSales 
from AggregatedSalesHistory as ash
join v_EnterpriseStructure as es on es.ProductSID = ash.ProductSID  
GROUP BY
    CategoryName,
    SubCategoryName
ORDER BY
    CategoryName,
    SubCategoryName
```

The existing examples I came across on the site about counting columns weren't clear.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: information_schema.columns has the info.

Answer (score 1):

For the 
case 1)

```
SELECT COUNT(COLUMN_NAME) 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_CATALOG = 'database' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
AND TABLE_NAME = 'aggregatedsaleshistory '
```